# accessing fragment's view from activity with function

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to dynamically change a text from a fragment textview inside de activity but I keep getting 'cannot obtain root' error. I tried to instantiate the textview inside onCreateView and inside onActivityCreated as well but it doesnt work. How can I change the text from a fragment textview inside the activity?

Fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Tab 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment Code:

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
    private TextView tv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
   }
    public void setText(String text){
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        TabFragment1 t1 = new TabFragment1();
        TabFragment2 t2 = new TabFragment2();
        TabFragment3 t3 = new TabFragment3();
        adapter.newFrag(t1);
        adapter.newFrag(t2);
        adapter.newFrag(t3);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        t1.setText("HELLO WORLD");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    List<Fragment> aFrag;
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        aFrag = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }
    public void newFrag(Fragment f){
        aFrag.add(f);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return aFrag.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace and make sure the fragment is attached to the activity before trying to access its view hierarchy

Comment: i'll post it asap thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to set text on view, but this view wasn't created, this fragment wasn't created. If You want to set text from activity you can pass **bundle** to fragment **arguments** with that text, and in fragment chceck bundle and set text. Later if you want to change text in this fragment then you can use your function.

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
private TextView tv;

public static TabFragment1 create(String text){
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("textdata",text);
   TabFragment1  f = new TabFragment1();
   f.setArguments(b);
   return f;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if(getArguments()!=null){
      tv.setText(getArguments().getString("textdata"));
    }

    return view;
}

    public void setText(String text){
    tv.setText(text);
}

}
```

In your activity create this fragment using static method:

```
 TabFragment1 t1 =TabFragment1.create("HELLO WORLD");
```

Hardcore execution of **your base** code is:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){t1.setText("HELLO WORLD");},300);
```

Comment: why is it not being created?(i thought using TabFragment1 t1 = new TabFragment1(); would do) how do i create it then?

Comment: This is only constructor. You have views when onCreateView is called.   Read about fragment lifecycles. You shouldnt keep references to your fragments. The Best solution is to use EventBus to communicating activity with fragments.

Comment: i understand. the whole point of this code though is that the fragment gets to be reused on another projects hence the function (get/set) to change textview text, this way i wouldnt need to change the fragment's xml anymore. i haven't read about eventbus but i've seen people using what i am trying as well as using listener or implementing on fragment's interfaces on activity. i read about fragment lifecycle and onactivitycreated is called after the layout has been inflated on onCreateView, so that means I the view is created, doesn't it?

Comment: If you call your method after instantionate fragment , your fragment may be not initialized.

Comment: i beg you pardon, but i can't understand what you mean. when exactly should i call the method? onResume?

Comment: thank you. i really wanted to see where my code was wrong.

Comment: TabFragment1 t1 = new TabFragment1(); t1.setText("HELLO WORLD"); this is only constructor called not onCreateView.